# When can we add $0$ back into the domain?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

Starting with $p(x) = \frac{q(x)}{x}$ (lets call this $1$)  for some polynomials $p$ and $q$. If I then multiply both sides by $x$, I get $xp(x) = q(x)$, which is true when $x=0$ if and only if $q(0) = 0$. In general, when you multiply by $x$ on both sides of an equation such as $(1)$, are you allowed to reintroduce $x=0$ into the domain?

Concrete Case:

Starting with $2 = \frac{2x}{x}$ we know this to be true when $x \ne$ $0$. Multplying by $x$ gives $2x = 2x$ which we know to be true for all $x$. As we started with $x \ne$ $0$, is the best we can say, $2x = 2x$ when $x \ne$ $0$ or are we  allowed to re-introduce $x=0$ into the domain.

Comment: If $p$ is a polynomial then $p(0)$ is not undefined. The equality $p(x)=\frac{q(x)}{x}$ is not valid for $x=0$, but that doesn't change the fact that $p(x)$ is defined or not at any point.

Comment: If $p(x)$ is a polynomial, then $p(0)$ is always defined. Did you mean something ng other than "polynomial?"

Comment: I have edited my question, hope it clears stuff up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, technically the domain of $p(x)$ does not include $0$.  In your example the domain of $p(x)=\frac{2x}{x}$ is $\mathbb{R}\setminus\{0\}$.

Now, the graph of this function $p(x)$ is a horizontal line with a "hole" above $x=0$.  As such, there is very little difference between the graph of $p(x)$ and the constant function that always outputs $2$, namely $\overline{p}(x) = 2$.  Technically however the domain of these two functions is different.  The domain of $\overline{p}(x)$ is all of $\mathbb{R}$ while the domain of $p(x)$ is $\mathbb{R}\setminus\{0\}$.

When one can "fix" a function (i.e. make it continuous by defining it at a point that is not in it's domain) one says that the original function (like your $p(x)$) has a "removable discontinuity" at that point.

Comment: Thanks, so just to clarify. We can multiply through by $x$ under the assumption that it is not equal to $0$. Then to "fix" $p(x)$ we can alter it to $t(x) = 2$, (by removing the hole). (Alternatively we can divide by $x$ under the assumption it is not $0$ aswell).

Comment: That is correct!